# UIDatePicker not shows proper in IOS 16.2

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, ios16

I am using `UIDatePicker` to pick a date from the user. In devices below IOS 16, it works fine, but in IOS 16+ devices, the calendar cuts from the bottom. Below is my code,

```
let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    datePickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
}
sender.inputView = datePickerView
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.datePickerValueChangedNew(sender:)), for:
UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

Issue:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Probably an iOS bug. I would just nest the date picker in a another `UIVIew` and manually give it some constraints.

Comment: You can also try to give DatePicker custom frame, let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.minX, y: view.frame.minY, width: view.frame.width, height: 150)). And manipulate "y" and "height" value. This is not a perfect solution, but you can give a try

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will try with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug in iOS 16. When the input view is presented, I see this message in the log:

```
[UICalendarView] UICalendarView's height is smaller than it can render its content in; defaulting to the minimum height.
```

My guess is that when presenting the input view, there is a one moment where a very small height for the date picker is required, "smaller than it can render its content". This causes the date picker to change its frame to use a default height. When the input view is fully presented, the date picker doesn't re-layout to account for the safe area for some reason.

You can simply work around this by nesting the date picker in a `UIView`. Constrain the date picker to the `UIView`'s safe areas:

```
// here I've used 700 as the height
// feel free to choose another number
let container = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 700))
container.addSubview(datePickerView)
datePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    datePickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    datePickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    datePickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    datePickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
])
textfield.inputView = datePickerView
```

Running this on the iPad 12.9 inch simulator, I got:

[image]

Adjust the constraints appropriately if you want more space on the buttom.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this and let you know.